# Why simple destructor does not delete the derived object if declared using base pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
int main()
{

    Base *p = new Derived;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

I have some confusion, why deleting p here won't delete the derived object ? Is it so that the derived object contains the sub-object of base type and pointer `p` is actually pointing to the base part ( sub-object) of the derived object. So when `delete p` is run it will only be able to delete the base class part of the object of the derived class and it will have undefined behavior for the derived part destruction. This will cause memory leaks. So to avoid memory leakage we need to manage to call both base and derived destructors of the object to avoid memory leakage! Is this so ? Is that the reason we need Virtual destructors for ?? So that when the base destructor is virtual, the derived class destrutor would override the base class's destructor (which is virtual). Please clarify??

Comment: Because - unfortunately - polymorphism is not automatic in C++. You'll have to define your destructor as `virtual`.

Comment: well....thats not an answer to my question

Comment: @userXXX Well, that is.

Comment: The base class destructor being virtual won't *override* the derived class destructor, it will run *as well*.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare a virtual destructor:

```
class Base {
   //etc...
   virtual ~Base();
};

class Derived {
   //etc...
   virtual ~Derived();
};

Base* p = new Derived();
delete p;
```

(Of course many things are missing above, including constructors)

Comment: I know that, was asking about the concept.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about the behavior in situation when base class has no virtual destructor, then your confusion is stemming for the fact hat you already have a number of pre-conceived misconceptions about the behavior of this `delete` expression

> "It will only be able to delete the base class part of the object"
>
> "This will cause memory leaks"

None of this makes any sense. There's no memory leaks here, and there's nothing as deterministic as being able to "delete the base class part" of it.

If the base class has no virtual destructor the behavior of such code is simply *undefined*. There are quite a few different ways that undefined behavior can manifest itself, including but not limited to improper destructor call, improper `operator delete` selection, heap corruption and, yes, "memory leaks", both direct and indirect. There are many different things that can get screwed up in this case. Not just some "memory leaks", as the popular misconception makes people believe. (Where does that popular bit about "memory leaks" come from. Does anyone know?)

So, you do need virtual destructor here. And the full list of reasons you need it can get quite long, if one decides to make a full effort to analyze it exhaustively. But in any case, this is an implementation detail. There's no specific explanation of what will really happen without tying it to a specific implementation.

As for the "conceptual" explanation... There's always the most obvious one: it is, of course, necessary to invoke the *proper* destructor in order to performs the proper destruction. Even if we simply limit out consideration to user-defined destruction steps (i.e. what the user explicitly wrote in their derived-class destructor), we still need destructor polymorphism to properly invoke *that* destructor.

However, there are also a number of other *internal* reasons. For example, in a typical implementation selection of the proper `operator delete` for raw memory deallocation also piggybacks on the virtuality of the destructor (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047225/187690), for example)

Comment: And if the base class has a virtual destructor (he doesn't tell us), then everything will work correctly.

Comment: It's good to memorize that OKay !!! keep the base class destructor virtual in this. No explanation conceptually ?? :(

Answer (score 2):

There are many questions in one, and the C++ syntax is unfortunately misleading, so let's review our bases.

---

> What happens in a destructor ?

When an object is *destructed* the language calls its destructor; the following sequence of events happen, in order:

- the body of the destructor is executed
- the attributes of the objects are destructed one at a time, in reverse order of construction (and thus declaration)
- the base objects are destructed one at a time, in reverse order of construction (and thus declaration)

*Note: `virtual` bases are destructed before attributes, but after the body is executed.*

The important point, here, is that even though a `Derived` method hides its `Base` counterpart (if any), in the case of constructor and destructor the base counterparts are automatically called for you at a well-defined point over which you have no control.

---

> What of `virtual` destructors ?

When a `Base` has a `virtual` destructor, the implicitly-declared or user-declared destructor in a `Derived` class will naturally *override* it. Similarly to other `virtual` methods it mean that when the destructor is called *unqualified* (that is, not as in `b.Base::foo()`) the call is in fact dispatched to the *final-overider*, that is the destructor of the most derived object (the real dynamic type of the object).

However, as seen in the previous point, this does not mean that the `Base` destructor itself will never run because destructors are special; you could think of the `Derived` destructor as being (automatically) implemented as:

```
Derived::~Derived(): ~Base(), ~attr0(), ~attr1() { ... }
```

with the code being executed right-to-left.

---

> And what of a `delete` expression on a `Base*` ?

Well, many people will think that `Base* b = ...; delete b;` is *desugared* as:

```
// NOT QUITE
Base* b = ...;
b.~Base(); // possibly virtual destructor
operator delete(&b);
```

However this is in fact incorrect. The issues are that:

- a `Derived` object address might differ from its `Base` subobject, and yet `operator delete` must be called with the exact pointer value that `operator new` returned.
- the `operator delete` invoked (which can be overloaded) must be resolved *at the definition point of the destructor*

Therefore, compilers need implement some magic; which is up to them. For example, compilers implementing the Itanium ABI (gcc, icc, clang, ...) will add a special entry to the v-table that contains a magic function that performs the pointer adjustments before calling the destructor of the most derived object and invoke `operator delete` with the right address. It could be seen as:

```
 class Derived: public Base {
 public:
     virtual ~Derived() override {}

     // FOR ILLUSTRATION PURPOSE ONLY
     // DON'T DO THIS AT HOME:
     // - you are forbidden to use `__` in your identifiers
     // - you are forbidden to call `delete this;` or any similar statement
     // FOR ILLUSTRATION PURPOSE ONLY
     virtual void __automagic_delete() {
         this->Derived::~Derived();
         operator delete(this);
     }
 };
```

---

> So, what if `Base::~Base` is not `virtual` ?

Well, formally this is **undefined behavior**.

In practice, two problems arise regularly:

1. Because `Derived::~Derived` is not called, any resource held by its attributes or another of its base classes are not released. This may cause memory leaks, file descriptor leaks, connector leaks, deadlocks, ...
2. If the `Derived` object has a different address than its `Base` subobject, then `operator delete` is invoked with an incorrect address... which in stringent implementation immediately leads to an `abort` and in less stringent ones might cause memory corruptions

But of course, since this is **undefined behavior**, really anything could happen, so this is just the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 1):

Deletion of an object via a pointer to its base class is undefined unless the base has a virtual destructor. Even with a virtual destructor, the order of deletion may not be what immediately comes to mind.

For more information, see [this destructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Destruction_sequence).