# No virtual destructor defined here

Tags: c++

This has been provided in my official notes but I spotted an error. Before I take it up to my instructor, I just thought of confirming it here with all my blood brothers- you guys.

```
#include <iostream.h>

class Base {
   public:
      virtual void display() { cout << "Base class" << endl; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
   // Nothing here
};

void main()
{
   Base * ptr;
   // Calls Base::display ( )
   ptr = new Base ;
   ptr ->display();
   delete ptr ;
   // Calls Base::display ( ) again
   ptr = new Derived ;
   ptr ->display();
   delete ptr ;
}
```

The output is:

```
Base class 
Base class
```

**I think the problem is in the very last line of the main function. I mean, since the destructor is not virtual, I don't think you can delete a dynamically allocated instance of the derived class type using the pointer of the base class type. What do you think?**

Comment: Well, another problem is `#include <iostream.h>`. There is no standard header with this name (there is however a standard header named `<iostream>`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual destructor and undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599225/virtual-destructor-and-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

> I mean, since the destructor is not virtual, I don't think you can delete a dynamically allocated instance of the derived class type using the pointer of the base class type. What do you think?

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573587/why-simple-destructor-does-not-delete-the-derived-object-if-declared-using-base) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220229/in-c-inheritance-derived-class-destructor-not-called-when-pointer-object-to-b) that this is undefined behavior.

> If the base class has no virtual destructor the behavior of such code is simply undefined.

> From the C++ standard:
>
> 5.3.5 Delete
>
> 3 In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It is, in fact, undefined behavior to do `delete ptrToBase;` where `ptrToBase` is of type `Base*` but actually points to an instance of `Derived*`, and `Base` lacks a virtual destructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I was just looking that up myself

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I updated my answer with links to other SO answers. I was already in the process of catching my own mistake, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is defined as virtual then the compiler will call the function using a pointer to the base using *dynamic binding*, i.e. the call to the actual function will go through the class vTable to find the relevant implementation of the function. If a function is not defined as virtual then the code generated by the compiler will use *static binding*, i.e. the compiler will simply call the function it knows. In other words, if you call a non-virtual function on the base class pointer which points to a derived class then the compiler will generate code for calling the base class implementation.

Now, destructor behavior is just a private case of the general behavior described above. As in the absence of a destructor implementation the compiler will generate a default non-virtual destructor for you, the destruction of an object using a base class pointer will just call the base class destructor. You can reproduce this behavior it easily by explicitly defining the non-virtual destructors for both base and derived classes and use the debugger to see that the base class version is the one being called.